# Which errorTypes are possible if the HTTP status from the response is 200?

Tags: php, foursquare

I try to program a php client for foursquare api. But i have problems to unterstand https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/responses

Which errorTypes are possible if code is 200?
Just "deprecated"?

Answer (score 1):

200 means everything was successful. If the api is returning an error it won't return a 200.

Comment: No. That´s wrong. foursquare can deliver an errorType "deprecated" with a code 200. But i don´t know if "deprecated" is the only possible errorType for code 200.

Comment: From reading that page it looks like deprecated is the only errorType you will see for a 200 response. Deprecated is usually seen more as a warning than an error, foursquare say they aim to use appropriate response codes so I don't imagine you'd ever see any other error type in a 200.